# Importar modulo dentro do loop é uma má prática?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bom dia pessoal, eu tenho um modulo javascript e importo ele no começo do meu código main/principal e nele executo um forEach, ainda nesse código principal tem loop que chama os métodos do modulo:

```
results.forEach(function(result) {
     for(const item of items .......){
        exampleModule.metodo(result, item)
     }
});
```

Até ai tudo bem, o problema é que os valores do modulo estão sendo misturados, o modulo não está dinâmico de acordo com o item Y do resultado X, ele meio que se "atrapalha" todo...

Eu pensei num jeito de resolver, não sei se é a melhor prática, declarar `const exampleModule = require('./modules/example.js')` dentro de um objeto e dar a esse objeto uma referencia, como por exemplo o ID do item, já que cada ID vai ser único:

```
let objetos = {}
results.forEach(function(result) {
     for(const item of items .......){
        objetos[item.id] = require('./modules/example.js')
        objetos[item.id].metodo(result, item)
     }
});
```

Resumindo, eu quero que cada item do loop crie uma instancia do modulo sem que eles sejam interferidos, se eu instanciar o modulo no item da posicao 0, tudo que tem no modulo só deverá ser usado por esse item 0, se for o item 1 a mesma coisa, o 1 n pode alterar valores do modulo que esta sendo usado pela posicao 0 e assim sucessivamente, é possível? Alguém pode me ajudar por gentileza?

Comment: "*o modulo não está dinâmico de acordo com o item Y do resultado X*" isso aqui ficou bastante confuso e dá a impressão que o que está fazendo pode ser um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878). Por que precisa que um módulo seja "dinâmico"? E o que seria esses valores Y e X?

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

Comment: Me desculpem, não soube me expressar da melhor forma a acabou ficando confuso. É que esse problema nunca aconteceu comigo, X e Y são posições do loop, o item e o resultado são objetos vem da API e são utilizados nos modulos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve importar o módulo apenas uma vez. A preferência é que seja no começo do seu arquivo. Se você usa valores incrementais dentro da sua função, você pode usar uma classe para criar uma nova instância a cada interação do `loop`:

```
class Exemplo {
  constructor() {
    this.valor = 0;
  }

  funcao(resultado, item) {
    this.valor = resultado + item;
    return this.valor;
  }
}

module.exports = Exemplo;
```

E utilizaria o módulo acima da seguinte forma:

```
const Exemplo = require('./Exemplo');

// ...
const exemplo = new Exemplo();
for (...) {
   console.log(exemplo.funcao(resultado, item));
}
```

Pode ser que seu problema também seja com relação à assincronismo, porém com as informações que foram dadas aqui não é possível sugerir uma solução.

Comment: Acho que você entendeu o meu problema, mas você viu que eu tenho um forEach? Esse forEach chama os resultados para serem executados em "paralelo", se eu instanciar a classe fora do loop ele vai acabar misturando da mesma forma

Comment: @viniciussvl tem 2 `loops` na sua pergunta. Você pode instanciar dentro do `forEach` e antes do `for`

Comment: Ah sim é que eu vi seu código não comparei com o meu, maravilha então Sorach, isso pode resolver o problema de vez, agradeço por me ajudar!

Comment: Então @Sorack eu fiz dessa forma mas parece que não funcionou, vi que no seu método "funcao" você passa os parametros, mas eu estou passando os parametros no construtor, será que pode ser isso?

Comment: @viniciussvl não sei, o seu exemplo não é testável, fica difícil opinar